# How to switch between the return type via the params in the doInBackground method android

Tags: android, class, http, https, parameters

Hi so I am working on a httpclient that will handle all the url request for my android app.What I want to do is be able to call the certain method I want to invoke. Right now all it does is call the basic httpUrlconnection. I have 3 other methods in this class that I want to call based on what is calling it. 
Any help on this will be great:

So here is how I am calling the method:

```
 MyHttpClient task = new MyHttpClient(username, password);
```

That is if I want to use it to login to a website. When I just want to use it with out a password I call it like this

```
MyHttpClient task = new MyHttpClient();
```

these ways work,but I don't know how to call the other three methods.
Here are my class that I have made;

```
public class MyHttpClient extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

private String username;
private String password;

//this is used if you need a password and username
//mainly for logins to a webserver
public MyHttpClient(String username, String password)
{
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
}

//used for image downloading
public MyHttpClient(){}



@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

    String url = params[0];
    return httpDownloadData(url);

}


//this is used for a simple http download of json files or xml file
//it must return a string fom the http request
private String httpDownloadData(String myUrl)
{
    String respone = null;
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

    try
    {
        URL url = new URL(myUrl);
        //put in the username and pssword for parmas to send to url
        //this is good for login
        if (username!=null)
        {
            Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
                @Override
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password.toCharArray());
                }
            });
        }

        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

        if(inputStream != null)
        {
            respone = streamToString(inputStream);
            inputStream.close();
        }

    }catch (IOException ie)
    {
        Log.d("IOExceptrion:", "In http downloader");
        ie.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        if(urlConnection != null)
        {
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
    }
    return respone;
}

//this is to download images from HTTP connections
private Bitmap httpBitmapDownloader(String myUrl)
{
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

    try {
        URL url = new URL(myUrl);
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        int statusCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();

        if (statusCode != 200)
        {
            return null;
        }

        InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        if(inputStream != null)
        {
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
            return bitmap;
        }


    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        if (urlConnection != null)
        {
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }

    }

    return null;
}



//download strings via https
//Todo Add the certificate handler so turst server
// TODO: 4/4/16 BKS needed for this
private String httpsDownloadData(String myUrl)
{

    String respone = null;
    HttpsURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    //get the cert handler

    try
    {
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("");
        String algorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
        TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(algorithm);
        tmf.init(keyStore);

        SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        context.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
        URL url = new URL(myUrl);
        if (username!=null)
        {
            Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
                @Override
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password.toCharArray());
                }
            });
        }
        urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(context.getSocketFactory());
       //urlConnection.setSSLSocketFactory(context.getSocketFactory());

        int statusCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
        Log.d("Status code: " , Integer.toString(statusCode));


        InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        if(inputStream != null)
        {
            respone = streamToString(inputStream);
            inputStream.close();
        }


    }catch (IOException e)
    {
        Log.d("downloading data: " , "in https webape");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        Log.d("Trustmanager issue:" , "Error");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
        Log.d("Keystore issues:", "Key needs att");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
        Log.d("Key management:" , "Key issue");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return respone;

}

private Bitmap httpsBitmapDownloader(String myUrl)
{
    HttpsURLConnection urlConnection = null;

    try
    {
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("");
        String algorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
        TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(algorithm);
        tmf.init(keyStore);

        SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        context.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
        URL url = new URL(myUrl);
        urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(context.getSocketFactory());

        int statusCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
        if(statusCode != 200){return null;}

        InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        if(inputStream != null)
        {
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
            return bitmap;
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("bitmap download: " , "Https issues");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (urlConnection != null)
        {
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
    }
    return null;
}

//this is used for downloading strings from an http or https connection
private String streamToString(InputStream is) throws IOException {

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    //add a fake parent to the line json data

    String line;
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line);
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: what exactly you want?

Comment: I want to change the doInBackground to be able to call what ever method of the 4 I want to. Right now all it does is call this method  httpDownloadData(url);

Comment: Don't use AsyncTasks and you'll be all good.

Comment: @Dogcat but isn't android HTTP stuff have to be AsyncTasks? I don't really know I just followed tutorials up to this point.

Comment: @MNM AsyncTask is just a rather weird thing and there were always a lot of mixed feelings about it (AFAIR, Google finally admitted that). In general you're only asked to perform network operations in a separate thread not necessarily via AsyncTask.

Comment: @MNM I mean, it's great for practice to try AsyncTasks out. But seriously there are tons of libraries out there aimed at making network interaction much easier for you. You will probably enjoy using them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call

> AsyncTask#execute(...)

with two params where the first one would represent a necessary method and the second would stand for its URL. Or wrap these two params in one single class.
Or switch to android-async-http, Retrofit or Ion since no one uses AsyncTask for http these days.

Comment: Thank you Dogcart I am looking into OKhttp as well as Ion now they look pretty good as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to return different types of results, modify your class definition from:

`... extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>`

to

`... extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Object>`

Since `String` and `Bitmap` are both a subclass of `Object`, it will be valid. Of course, then you still need to modify your `doInBackground(...)` to return `Object` also.

Comment: How would I go about changing the doInBackgournd method to use different methods? Based off the params?

Comment: Well how would you detect which one you want?

Comment: String url = params[0];
        if(url.contains("https"))
        {
            Log.d("Using: " , "Https");
            return httpsDownloadData(url);
        }else
        {
            Log.d("Using "," HTTP");
            return httpDownloadData(url);
        }

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that in more optimized way. 
You should write a separate asynctask for each call (different url).
Manage parameters through constructor or via String parameters of asynctask.
If necessary, make class as abstract , so  that you can do the necessary changes.

Comment: >You can achieve that in more optimized way.
How is that optimized?